# How to read an Excel file(97-03) in Visual Basic 6.0

Tags: vb6

Can anybody tell me how to read an Excel file in visual basic 6.0 and import all the values into a listview or datagridview,want to use a simple and efficient technique to achieve this. can anyone help me to solve this

Comment: i know these are all outdated ,but need it for one last time

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should import data from an Excel file into a ListView:

```
    Dim ExcelObj As Object
    Dim ExcelBook As Object
    Dim ExcelSheet As Object
    Dim i As Integer

    Set ExcelObj = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set ExcelSheet = CreateObject("Excel.Sheet")

    ExcelObj.WorkBooks.Open App.Path & "\ExcelFile.xls"

    Set ExcelBook = ExcelObj.WorkBooks(1)
    Set ExcelSheet = ExcelBook.WorkSheets(1)

    Dim l As ListItem
    lvwList.ListItems.Clear
    With ExcelSheet
    i = 1
    Do Until .cells(i, 1) & "" = ""
        Set l = lvwList.ListItems.Add(, , .cells(i, 1))
        l.SubItems(1) = .cells(i, 2)
        l.SubItems(2) = .cells(i, 3)
        l.SubItems(3) = .cells(i, 4)
        i = i + 1
    Loop

    End With

    ExcelObj.WorkBooks.Close

    Set ExcelSheet = Nothing
    Set ExcelBook = Nothing
    Set ExcelObj = Nothing
```

Comment: l.SubItems(1) = .cells(i, 2) at this line i am getting invalid property error

Comment: Thank you i tried to add a value to the column which doesnt exist.

Comment: xaisoft,while reading excel all the codes i tried are keeping the excel in memory and read it,is it possible to do the same without putting the file in the memory,if it sounds silly please leave this comment

Comment: this line " Set ExcelSheet = CreateObject("Excel.Sheet") " is it relevant? the same variable is set 2 lines afeter before being used...

Answer (score 2):

I'd be a lot more likely to use a grid control of some sort rather than a ListView for this, but...

Since you're merely bringing in values without metadata (formatting) you can use one of Jet's Excel IISAMs to do this and it even works on machines where Excel is not installed!

```
Dim SheetName As String
Dim RS As ADODB.Recordset
Dim LI As ListItem
Dim I As Integer

'Look up 1st Worksheet (or just hardcode its Name).
'
'Notes:
'  o Can use Excel 8.0 or Excel 5.0 to read most Excel 7.0/97
'    Workbooks, but there is no IISAM specifically for Excel 7.0.
'  o Use HDR=Yes if your Worksheet has a header row.
With CreateObject("ADOX.Catalog")
    .ActiveConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='" _
                      & App.Path & "\sample.xls';" _
                      & "Extended Properties='Excel 5.0;HDR=No'"
    SheetName = .Tables(0).Name
    Set RS = New ADODB.Recordset
    Set RS.ActiveConnection = .ActiveConnection
End With
'The "Table" name can be a range too, e.g. [Sheet1$A1C7]
With RS
    .Open "[" & SheetName & "]", _
          , _
          adOpenForwardOnly, _
          adLockReadOnly, _
          adCmdTable
    ListView.ListItems.Clear
    ListView.View = lvwReport
    For I = 0 To .Fields.Count - 1
        ListView.ColumnHeaders.Add , , .Fields(I).Name
    Next
    Do Until .EOF
        Set LI = ListView.ListItems.Add(, , CStr(.Fields(0).Value))
        For I = 1 To .Fields.Count - 1
            LI.SubItems(I) = CStr(.Fields(I).Value)
        Next
        .MoveNext
    Loop
    .Close
End With
```